# I can't seem to be able to start a nodeJS service

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start a service:

```
c:\MongoUni\Ex3\chapter3>node index.js
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.js:48:37
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option auth.js:48:37
Listening on port 3000!
```

I get this error

```
c:\MongoUni\Ex3\chapter3\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app is trying to connect to mongodb at port 27017 but you don't have one running on your machine. Here are instructions on how to install it on Windows (which i'm guessing you're running based on the filepath) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: thx, just had to run:
c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod